# Multiple select statements give multiple answer sets

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a few SELECT statements that I would like to have in one SQL file.

```
File.sql
SELECT * FROM A
SELECT * FROM B
SELECT * FROM C
```

I want to run File.sql directly in Teradata and be able to see the results from the different select statements. These results are quite different and should not be in the same answer set. It doesn't matter if the reult is shown in Teradata or stored in some file. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? FYI: My user rights are limited, I can't e.g create stored procedures.

This question was considered similar to "Run multiple queries from 1 SQL file showing result in multiple tables". It is similar but not identical. The difference i mainly how the result set it represnted. In that question the requirement was to store it in one file but in this question I don't care how the result set is displayed. Hence I hope for an easier answer here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run multiple queries from 1 SQL file showing result in multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475865/run-multiple-queries-from-1-sql-file-showing-result-in-multiple-tables)

Comment: My suggestion is to search for `Multiple Result Sets` http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multiple+resultset+sql

Comment: @Jaider: The problem is that those solutions (that I found) implies using stored procedures which I don't have access to do.

Comment: @Jarlh: You are right. The questions are similar. However, this solution is probably easier than the other one.

Comment: How do you run those queries, BTEQ on command line, SQL Assistant, TD Studio, etc.? What do you mean by "answer set"? Each SELECT returns an answer set by default...

Comment: I would say this exclusively depends on the SQL client you are using. Some might display all three results, some might only display the last one and some might not even run this at all.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what tools you have access to this is difficult to answer.

However one of the simplest ways to get multiple answer sets is using SQL Assistant.

for example:
in your query window type or paste the following

```
  SELECT * FROM dbc.DBCInfo;
  SELECT * FROM dbc.DBCInfo;
  SELECT * FROM dbc.DBCInfo;
```

in your menu select file ->export results

hit F5 (or the green feet) 
it will prompt you for a location and filename enter where you want and file name.

it will then save the results like below

```
     RELEASE,14.10.02.11
     VERSION,14.10.02.12
     LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE,Standard

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     RELEASE,14.10.02.11
     VERSION,14.10.02.12
     LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE,Standard

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     RELEASE,14.10.02.11
     VERSION,14.10.02.12
     LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE,Standard
```

You can also set in you options to save the sql with each query etc.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can login using BTEQ then you can do the following through a script :

.LOGON env/user_id,password
.SET WIDTH 3000
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF;

.EXPORT report file= file1
Select * from A;

.EXPORT report file= file2
Select * from B;

.EXPORT report file= file3
Select * from C;

.EXPORT reset;
.LOGOFF ;